# UIPopover changes position when keyboard appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, ios7, uipopovercontroller

UI popover points to the correct UIButton as long as i don't tap on the UITextfield. the moment I do that, the popover moves somewhere to the top left position. the moment keyboard closes, it moves back to the correct position. After googling a bit, I could see many people facing similar issues but couldn't find a proper solution. Here is how I am showing the popover

```
[self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:[sender bounds] inView:sender
            permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```